# How re-write without negativity? 'may never directly prohibit private party actions, this does not mean that it cannot have horizontal direct effects'

Tags: legalese

I don't know  EU or law. To improve English, I want try re-rewriting long sentences without negative words because I understand ["Don't you ever talk like that to me again", but not "Don't you never silence like that to me never"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15336/5306). Is "negative" correct adjective?

Robert Schütze. [*European Union Law* 2 ed. 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). p 116.

> But even when directives have direct effect, they generally do not have horizontal
>   direct effects. Why has the Court shown such ‘childish’ loyalty to the
>   no-horizontal-
>   direct-
>   effect
>   rule? Has that rule not created more constitutional
>   problems than it solves? And is the Court perhaps discussing a ‘false problem’?
>   **(1) For if the Court simply wishes to say that an (unimplemented) directive may
>   never directly prohibit *private* party actions [PPAs], (2) this does not mean that it cannot
>   have horizontal direct effects [HDE] in civil disputes challenging the legality of *State*
>   actions.**<sup>199</sup>
>
> <sup>199</sup> This – much – simpler reading of the substance of the case law would bring directives
>   close to the normative character of Art. 107 TFEU – prohibiting State aid. For while the
>   provision can be invoked as against the State as well as against a private party, it cannot
>   prohibit private aids by private companies.

Here's my guess for (1). Correct?

> For if the Court simply wishes to say that an (unimplemented) directive can just sometime indirectly prohibit PPAs

Here's my guess for (2). Correct?

> this means horizontal direct effects are possible in civil disputes [I skip rest].

Comment: Bounty or no, this question is completely incoherent. What does "negative" mean? Your guess for (1) contains several negatives and other triggers, and neither is understandable out of context. Negatives do not cancel out easily and can't be dispensed with. Unfortunately. As a result, this will attract answers only by those with little knowledge but a desire for points. Points are irrelevant; context is everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler i don't know linguistics term. but how you not understand what i try to ask? i want to write out words like "never" — there's one — and "not"  — shows up two, one in "cannot"?

Comment: @JohnLawler what is the linguistic term? Negator? thanks!

Comment: **Why** would you want to rewrite the sentence?

Comment: If you want to know about negation, start [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), then [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) for the basics. It's part of [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). It's not simple.

Comment: @jsw29 my post answers you now

Comment: @ElaineNai, the quoted passage about the EU law is not at all analogous to 'Don't you never silence like that to me never'. The passage is somewhat complex, but grammatical and unambiguous. Its complexity is necessitated by the complexity of its subject matter, and, as explained by gnasher729 and KrisW, it can't be made much easier to read without distorting its point.

Answer (score 7):

Don't even try. This is a law text. The slightest change to its meaning would be fatal. And even if you managed to modify the text correctly, the existence of two different versions is at least confusing.

To me, the "negativity" as you call it is one hundred percent necessary to express exactly what is meant. As an example, "may never directly prohibit" is not the same as "can just sometime indirectly prohibit". Not at all. Actually, it means something totally different. The first statement is about direct prohibition, the second about indirect prohibition. Totally different things. And the suggestions in the other answers have the same problem, they significantly change the meaning of the text.

Answer (score 3):

### The sentence was a negative statement - it *needs* a negating word

There is actually no way to preserve the meaning of the original legal text without using a negating word or a using a construction that negates one of its clauses, simply because the meaning of the sentence was that the two things it talks about are *not* linked.

Secondly, there's no grammatical transformation you can do on this sentence to remove those negating words, because the sentence is a type of logical formula that cannot be inverted.

#### Grammar problems: expressing that two things are unrelated

Don't be thrown by the presence of *if*: this sentence is not expressing a conditional relationship. In fact, the information being conveyed here is the opposite: that the two clauses describe independent things, even though they may seem related at first glance. To see this more clearly, let's condense the two long clauses so we can see the structure of the sentence better.

Let *X* be the statement "*an (unimplemented) directive may never directly prohibit private party actions [PPAs]*"

... and let *Y* be the statement "*it [a directive] cannot have horizontal direct effects [HDE] in civil disputes challenging the legality of State actions*"

Now the sentence looks like this:

- "if

  - the Court wishes to say *X*
- this doesn't mean that

  - *Y*"

That's pretty simple isn't it? If this was mathematical logic, we could also say "X does not imply Y", or using the mathematical notation for such things:

- `~(X→Y)`

The squiggle means "not" (or "is false"), the arrow means "implies".

#### Logical problems: inverting implications

So, why am I talking about logic?  Because knowing a little bit about logic is important if you want to avoid the mistake that a couple of answers have made.

If "*X* implies *Y*" (or "*X* does not imply *Y*"), one cannot simply negate the two clauses *X* and *Y* and still have the sentence mean the same thing. Here's the famous example:

- X = "the animal is a dog"
- Y = "it has four legs"
- (X→Y) = "if the animal a dog, this means that it has four legs"

Now, invert the clauses *X* and *Y*:

- ~X = "the animal is *not* a dog"
- ~Y = "it does *not* have four legs"
- (~X → ~Y) = "if the animal is not a dog, this means that it does not have four legs"

Okay, that's plainly nonsense (consider cats), so let's invert the implication too:

- ~X = "the animal is not a dog"
- ~Y = "it does not have four legs"
- ~(~X → ~Y) = "if the animal is not a dog, it *does not mean* that it does not have four legs"

Incidentally, we've now arrived at the structure of the orignally-quoted sentence (it's almost like I went back and changed my examples!).  But, have a look at where we are and where we came from:

- ~(~X → ~Y) = "if the animal is not a dog, it does not mean that it does not have four legs"
- (X→Y) = "if the animal is a dog, it means that it has four legs"

These two sentences don't mean the same thing at all.  The first sentence says nothing about animals that *are* dogs, the second says nothing about animals that are not dogs.

That's the problem: implications can't be negated in the way that simple statements of fact can.  You need to re-word the sentence.

However, in the original sentence the "X does not mean Y" *is* the most important idea being conveyed, so you really need to leave it in place.

Answer (score 2):

Answer coming from somebody well-versed in the principles of EU law, such as direct effect.

(1) I don't think *just sometimes indirectly* is an improvement to *never directly*. You still have a negation (it's in the prefix *in-*), but you have more words. Moreover, I think it does not precisely reflect the meaning of the original. It would rather be something along the lines of:

> For if the Court simply wishes to say that an (unimplemented) directive might prohibit PPAs indirectly, at most.

The crucial point is that the alleged court statement does not make a definite assertion about whether indirect prohibitions are legally possible. It just denies direct prohibitions.

(2) The same for (2). It's not quite accurate. The original sentence does not say for certain that HDE is possible. It just says that impossibility is not a necessary conclusion from (1). In other words – we don't know if HDE is possible here, but we know that (1) is not a reason that makes it impossible.

That being said, HDE is an established principle and would apply here, according to how I understand the author.

Answer (score -1):

**It can be written as below:**

> 1. For if the Court wants to say that (an unimplemented) directive directly not prohibit private party actions
> 2. It may have horizontal direct effects in civil disputes too.

Comment: Sorry,  but no,  it can't be rewritten that way.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: You've got most of it, but there is at least one glaring error in the first part involving a verb. See if you can spot it.

Comment: To clear up the confusion: It's usually not *want*, but *wants* (indicative simple present) or *wanted* (subjunctive simple present or indicative simple past). Then there also is the use of a plural verb with a collective noun, as in *The football team have won the match.* But this is not usual for a court, because it is not seen as a collective of judges but as a single body.

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple: since this is formal language, just reverse the double negative to find the meaning.

Reverse the 2 negative words in each phrase to their opposites. Since they modify (and negate) each other, the meaning will be similar:

(1) "For if the Court simply wishes to say that an (unimplemented) directive may never directly prohibit private party actions [PPAs],"

becomes

"For if the Court simply wishes to say that an (unimplemented) directive may always directly allow private party actions [PPAs],"

(2) "this does not mean that it cannot have horizontal direct effects [HDE] in civil disputes challenging the legality of State actions.199"

becomes

"this means it can have horizontal direct effects [HDE] in civil disputes challenging the legality of State actions.199"

***References:***

1. The New Oxford American Dictionary has the following note [1] about the double negative:

"The rules dictate that the two negative elements cancel each other out to give an affirmative statement, so that, logically, I don't know nothing would be interpreted as I know something... However, the double negative should be used judiciously because it may cause confusion or annoy the reader."

2. "In formal use, negation is 'mathematical': double negations cancel out..." [2]

[1] https://www.lexico.com/definition/double_negative

[2] https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/829/how-is-double-negation-interpreted-in-english

Comment: (1) would be true if *directly allow* was the opposite of *directly prohibit*. But it's thinkable the ECJ does not distinguish between direct and indirect allowing. And indeed, I think it doesn't.

Comment: (2) What if the ECJ later holds that it cannot have this form of HDEM; the reason being not (1) but some different reason? This would contradict your phrasing, but not the original's. So, rephrasing and original are not equivalent.